# Date object from react-datepicker not getting saved

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern, react-datepicker

Apologies in advance for the abomination of a code you are about to see...

I am relatively new to React and programming in general, and I'm trying to create a MERN application with react-hooks-form to streamline the process. The component I have issues with is the editing portion. I was unable to figure out how to handle controlled inputs in hooks-form so I tried to circumvent the problem by using state to store the values in two different states, which I realize defeats the purpose of using hooks-forms.

Everything so far works fine with the exception of the `dateOfBirth` which is a required field. On submit, however I get a 400 error and says that `dateOfBirth` is required.

```
export default function EditMember(props) {

    const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
    const [member, setMember] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        dateOfBirth: null,
        gender: '', 
        address: '',
        phoneNumber: ''
    })


    const onChangeDate = date => {
        setDate(date)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/members/${props.match.params.id}`)
            .then(res => {
                setMember({
                    firstName: res.data.firstName,
                    lastName: res.data.lastName,
                    dateOfBirth: Date.parse(res.data.dateOfBirth),
                    address: res.data.address,
                    phoneNumber: res.data.phoneNumber,
                    gender: res.data.gender
                });
            })           
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/members/${props.match.params.id}`)
            .then(res => {
                setDate(res.data.dateOfBirth);
            })
    }, []);

    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const onSubmitData = data => {
        const updatedMember = {
            firstName: data.firstName,
            lastName: data.lastName,
            dateOfBirth: date,
            address: data.address,
            phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
            gender: data.gender,
        } 
        axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/members/update/${props.match.params.id}`, updatedMember)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    }

    return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitData)}>
                <div>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="firstName" 
                        defaultValue={member.firstName}
                        placeholder="First name" 
                        ref={register} 
                    />
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="lastName" 
                        defaultValue={member.lastName}
                        placeholder="Last name" 
                        ref={register} 
                    />
                    <span>Male</span>
                    <input 
                        type="radio" 
                        value="Male" 
                        name="gender"
                        ref={register}
                    /> 
                    <span>Female</span> 
                        <input 
                        type="radio" 
                        value="Female" 
                        name="gender" 
                        ref={register} 
                    /> 
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="address" 
                        placeholder="Address" 
                        ref={register}
                        defaultValue={member.address}
                    <input  
                        type="text" 
                        name="phoneNumber" 
                        placeholder="Phone Number" 
                        ref={register} 
                        defaultValue={member.phoneNumber}
                    />
                    <DatePicker
                        selected = {member.dateOfBirth}
                        onChange = {onChangeDate} 
                        placeholderText="Select date"   
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Edit Log</button>
            </form> 
    )
}
```

Any reason as to why this occurs? Besides that, any insight into how I can refactor the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use react-datepicker with react-hook-form you need to utilize react-hook-form's Controller component. Reference here: [Integrating Controlled Inputs](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs).

The following component declaration illustrates wrapping a react-datepicker DatePicker component in a react-hook-form Controller component. It is registered with react-hook-form using `control={control}` and then renders the DatePicker in the Controller components `render` prop.

```
const { register, handleSubmit, control, setValue } = useForm();

//...

<Controller
  name="dateOfBirth"
  control={control}
  defaultValue={date}
  render={() => (
    <DatePicker
      selected={date}
      placeholderText="Select date"
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  )}
/>
```

The DatePicker still needs to control its value using handleChange and a `date` state, but we can use this same handler to update the value of the registered input for react-hook-form using [setValue()](https://react-hook-form.com/api#setValue).

```
const handleChange = (dateChange) => {
  setValue("dateOfBirth", dateChange, {
    shouldDirty: true
  });
  setDate(dateChange);
};
```

Your full component (without API calls) might look like the following. `onSubmitData()` is called by react-hook-form's `handleSubmit()` and here logs the output of the form, including the updated DatePicker value.

Here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-sea-pkrli).

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <EditMember />
    </div>
  );
}

function EditMember() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, control, setValue } = useForm();
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState(new Date(Date.now()));

  const onSubmitData = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    
    // axis.post(
    //   `http://localhost:5000/members/update/${props.match.params.id}`,
    //    data).then(res => console.log(res.data))
  }

  const handleChange = (dateChange) => {
    setValue("dateOfBirth", dateChange, {
      shouldDirty: true
    });
    setDate(dateChange);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitData)}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="First name"
          ref={register}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          placeholder="Last name"
          ref={register}
        />
        <span>Male</span>
        <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" ref={register} />
        <span>Female</span>
        <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender" ref={register} />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="address"
          placeholder="Address"
          ref={register}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="phoneNumber"
          placeholder="Phone Number"
          ref={register}
        />
        <Controller
          name="dateOfBirth"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={date}
          render={() => (
            <DatePicker
              selected={date}
              placeholderText="Select date"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          )}
        />

        <button type="submit">Edit Log</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output

```
//Output

Object {firstName: "First", lastName: "Last", gender: "Male", address: "Addy", phoneNumber: "fon"…}
 firstName: "First"
 lastName: "Last"
 gender: "Male"
 address: "Addy"
 phoneNumber: "fon"
 dateOfBirth: Wed Aug 19 2020 17:20:12 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I came across the Controller component while researching the issue but didn't really grasp much of it. Appreciate your clarification, I will be refactoring the code to reflect these changes.

Comment: No problem, glad it will help. Perhaps you'd accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually figure out what was wrong. There was a typo in the update route that blocked the field from being recorded. I was able to get it working with pretty much the exact same code.

My apologies for not going through them thoroughly.